# How to Bench mark code using .Net Framework 4 on Desktop application

Tags: c#, desktop-application, benchmarking

I have written my Desktop application but it's a little slow at times so I am trying to Optimize it as much as possible.  Trouble is I don't know how.

Here is the code I have questions about

```
if (((mainRibbonForm)Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent)).myParentScopeVar == false)
{
   //something goes here

}

//VS

if (myLocalScopeVar == false)
{
    //something goes here
}
```

All the objects are created in mainRibbonForm and assigned,  It seems that I can't call something like this.

```
mainRibbonForm.myparentScopeVar == false
```

So while in the last object, I just walked backwards to grab the variable using the Parent command variable.

I am not sure if I should always look at the parent scope for the variable or assign the variable to the last control as a localscope and only update it when the parent scope variable changes, which is not very often, but it does change.

I have some of these in timers and peppered every where in the code..   I am very new to C# and I translated everything from VB.Net to C#  I am just trying to learn the correct or the best practices of programming in C#

Which is Faster and uses less resources?

How to I benchmark on my own next time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this code is overkill and horrible to see:

```
if (((mainRibbonForm)Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent)).myParentScopeVar == false)
{
   //something goes here   
}
```

Instead of this I prefer use a static variable and then call it using `mainRibbonForm.myParentScopeVar`. So you could insert this in your class:

```
public static bool myParentScopeVar;
```

Or you can pass this boolean through the constructors.

---

If you want to do a benchmark use the [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class that is a high resolution timer to measure how long your code will run and loop the code that you are testing more times to get a medium time that includes his best and worst performances:

```
Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (((mainRibbonForm)Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent)).myParentScopeVar == false)
    {
         //something goes here   
    }
}

timer.Stop();  
TimeSpan timespan = timer.Elapsed;

MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds / 10));    

timer.Restart();

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (myLocalScopeVar == false)
    {
         //something goes here
    }
}

timer.Stop();  
TimeSpan timespan = timer.Elapsed;

MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds / 10));
```

I think that my solution and your second solution using `myLocalScopeVar` are more efficient.

Comment: I just tried your solution and I am getting 00:00:00 as the return for both, does this mean they are equally as fast? I even bumped them up to 5000 in the for loop, when ran it does not take any time at all.

Comment: Ok I just increased the loops to 500000 and I got 00:00:21 on the first, and 00:00:00 on the second.